# how do i center my css navigation bar

Tags: css

here is my code

```
#cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li, #cssmenu span, #cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu:after, #cssmenu ul:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
    background: #646464 url(images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(100%, #4a4a4a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#646464', endColorstr='#4a4a4a', GradientType=0);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
    filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(100%, #4a4a4a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#646464', endColorstr='#4a4a4a', GradientType=0);
    filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
    background: #4a4a4a url(images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left top;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #8a8a8a), color-stop(50%, #707070), color-stop(51%, #626262), color-stop(100%, #787878));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
    border-top: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
    border-right: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 35px;
    filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover {
    background: #8a8a8a url(images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(50%, #4a4a4a), color-stop(51%, #3b3b3b), color-stop(100%, #525252));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
    filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    left: -1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /* IE7 */
    *width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
    border-top: 0 none;
    border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
    display: block;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 9px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Please tell us what you've already tried, and explain why it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this this:

```
#cssmenu ul {
  width: <somenumber>px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```